# Join tables displaying one column based on max of another

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm joining some tables and need to return values based upon a max value without actually returning the max value column itself.

Table1

```
+------------+----------+---------+
| EmployeeID | TaskTime | JobType |
+------------+----------+---------+
|       1000 | 5:14:00  | Read    |
|       1000 | 5:42:00  | Write   |
|       1000 | 6:14:00  | Write   |
+------------+----------+---------+
```

Table2

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+
| EmployeeID | ClockType | JobDetail | JobType |
+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+
|       1000 | 5:03:00   | This      | Read    |
|       1000 | 5:21:00   | That      | Write   |
+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

What I want to now return is the JobDetail corresponding to the last ClockType before the TaskTime. So something like this:

```
+------------+----------+---------+-----------+
| EmployeeID | TaskTime | JobType | JobDetail |
+------------+----------+---------+-----------+
|       1000 | 5:14:00  | Read    | This      |
|       1000 | 5:42:00  | Write   | That      |
|       1000 | 6:14:00  | Write   | That      |
+------------+----------+---------+-----------+
```

My query I'm using is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT X.*, t2.JobDetail
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.EmployeeID, t1.TaskTime, t1.JobType
    FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE t1.EmployeeID=10000
) X
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on (X.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID) and (X.JobType = t2.JobType) and (t2.ClockTime < X.TaskTime)
```

This returns all rows where ClockTime < TaskTime, as expected. I just cant seem to figure out how to show only the last ClockTime before TaskTime. I tried changing my JOIN like the following but it returns all null values for JobDetail:

```
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT row_number() over(partition by ClockTime order by ClockTime desc) rn, JobDetail, ClockTime as time2
    FROM Table2) t2
        on (X.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID) and (X.JobType = t2.JobType) and (t2.ClockTime < X.TaskTime)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `TOP` and `Apply` to get the max values.

```
select      *
from        Table1                       as t1
cross apply (   select      top 1
                            JobDetail
                from        Table2 as t2
                where       t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
                and         t1.JobType = t2.JobType
                and         t1.TaskTime >= t2.ClockType
                order by    ClockType desc) as jt
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/421f13/1)

Using `Row_Number()`

```
select  *
from    (   select  t1.EmployeeID
                    , t1.TaskTime
                    , t1.JobType
                    , t2.JobDetail
                    , row_number() over (partition by t1.EmployeeID, t1.JobType, t1.TaskTime
order by t2.ClockType desc) as Rn
            from    Table1 as t1
            join    Table2 as t2 on  t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
                                 and t1.JobType = t2.JobType
                                 and t1.TaskTime >= t2.ClockType) as t
where   Rn = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/421f13/2)